# No return statement but still returning None

Tags: python

My function is just to modify a list.However, I don't want it to return anything not even 'None' and yet it returns 'None'. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: A function has to return *something*, even if it is just an implicit `None`. I don't think there's a way around that.

Comment: Python functions without a return statement return `None` by default. That's just how it is. What would you rather it return? I suggest you leave it at returning *nothing* as in `None` if you don't want to return something. That's the idiomatic way of doing it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not return anything"? How would that work? (E.g. what would `x = foo()` do?)

Comment: if you don't want it to return `None` make it return something you wouldn't care of, such as `return "I am crazy"`

Comment: Oh, I see thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: No, there is not a meaningful way around default return of `None` in Python.**

In Python, returning an implied `None` is the closest you can do to "return nothing". This is different to e.g. C where a `void` function declaration would prevent assignment to a variable. This behaviour is part of the Python language for consistency, because

```
x = MyFunc()
```

must define and store some value in `x`. Similarly, uses such as

```
OtherFunc( 1, 2, MyFunc() )
```

or

```
[ 1, 2, 3, MyFunc() ]
```

or

```
MyFunc() * 3
```

All need to have some behaviour. With an implied return value of `None`, these issues are solved in a particular way in Python.

It doesn't *have* to be this way - in principle if someone were to re-design this part of Python there could be a few different self-consistent approaches - for instance Python *could* have some special value that could only be returned from function calls and if it was found to be inside any other expression that could raise an error. Worth noting that in some cases, such as `3 * MyFunc()`, a return value of `None` *will* raise an error in this way - but you cannot rely on that happening immediately in all possible unwanted scenarios based on the function definition.

However, Python returns implicit `None`. Changing this would affect any code/libraries that rely on the behaviour in a global way, or add awkward context-parsing requirements to the language because the feature necessarily would need to work both inside function definitions and where those functions were used.